# I am getting the following error when launching jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TONY\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\TONY\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 58, in 
raise ImportError(_("The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have %s") % tornado.version)
ImportError: The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have 4.5.3
```

Btw i have tornado version 6.2 but i am still getting the above error....

Comment: probably you are in the wrong environment, `python -m pip install tornado`

Comment: You can check which packages you have installed with `conda list` before installing to confirm that you're in the right environment.

Comment: check the following things: 1. the python you are using, 2. the virtual env 3. which package manager you are using(pip? conda?...)